# Why does this declarative pipeline fail in my shared library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a shared library containing a declarative pipeline used in a repo Jenkinsfile (it is in fact called through an intermediate): Jenkinsfile -> bupJavadocApiPipeline.groovy -> bupMavenPipeline.groovy

Jenkinsfile (shared library is implicit):

```
bupJavadocApiPipeline {}
```

bupJavadocApiPipeline.groovy:

```
def call(body, Map defaults = [:]) {
    if (defaults.mavenGoals == null) defaults.mavenGoals = 'javadoc:javadoc package'
    bupMavenPipeline(body,defaults)
}
```

bupMavenPipeline.groovy (bupParameters does the DELEGATE_FIRST trick):

```
def call(body, defaults = [:]) {

if (defaults.maven == null) defaults.maven='MVN3'
if (defaults.mavenGoals == null) defaults.mavenGoals='package'
if (defaults.jdk == null) defaults.jdk='JDK8'
if (defaults.buildsToKeep == null) defaults.buildsToKeep='10'

def parameters = bupParameters(body,defaults)

pipeline {
    options {
        timestamps()
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: "${parameters.buildsToKeep}"))
    }
    agent ('docker') {
    tools {
        maven "${parameters.maven}"
        jdk "${parameters.maven}"
    }
    stages {    
        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true clean ${parameters.mavenGoals}"
            }
            post {
                success {
                    junit '**/target/surefire-report/**/*.xml'                  
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}

}
```

This fails with:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'options' found among steps [...
```

Versions are Jenkins 2.162 and Pipeline 2.6, but so many web resources say this is supported since September 2017!
I can make it all work if I only do scripted pipeline in bupMavenPipeline.groovy, but I like the "safety" of declarative (and there seem to be many more resources on that then on scripted).

Can you see what is tripping me up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inlining into the actual Jenkinsfile Jenkins kindly helped me to identify the problem:

agent ('docker') { ... }

should be

agent { label 'docker' }